# Why Output File Name Doesn't Include Content Hash From Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Hi I have the following in my webpack prod config:

```
output: {
filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
publicPath: '/container/latest/'
}
```

but the output does not include the content hash. My file is always named as `main.js` not `main.[contenthash].js`

I'm using `webpack version 5.59.1`.

I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Tty to use `chunkFilename`

Comment: @AliYaghoby I just did, still no change

Comment: Use `hash` instead of `contenthash`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62356238/get-webpack-to-output-the-generated-hash-to-a-config-file

Comment: @AliYaghoby none of them work. my webpack does not seem to recognise any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the problem. I was running webpack.dev.js instead of webpack.prod.js.